# How can I configure ScrewTurn Wiki to use SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, screwturn

I'm trying to configure the excellent ScrewTurn Wiki product on my server, and haven't been able to make sense of [the documentation](http://www.screwturn.eu/Plugins.ashx#SQL_Server_UsersPages_Storage_Provider_BBCBDG_10).

I'd like to configure it to use SQL Server for storage.  Do I still need to specify a valid value for the PublicDirectory key in web.config?

This is how I've tried to configure the connection so far, but obviously I'm missing something else:

```
<add name="WikiData"
  connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I can't even get the page to load without complaining about the PublicDirectory key after adding this connection string.  Before I added the connection string, the site came up fine without SQL Server implementation.  I'm not even getting a chance to see if the DB connection works and don't know what to name it here, if the name makes any difference in the key.

How can I get this working properly?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question i'm afraid, but you should definitely ask on the ScrewTurn Setup and Deployment forums: http://www.screwturn.eu/forum/viewforum.php?f=1&sid=e1f57a516e77238842ea18ee7a81eb0b

Dario's generally pretty good about answering questions, plus you may find existing answers already posted for the benefit of other users.

Comment: already did that at the time I posted this bud.  I don't just post stuff before researching the hell out of something when I hit a wall.  Besides his directions are terrible.  Sorry I love Dario and everything but the docs have a little work that is needed which is why I'll blog about how to set this up...there are a few things not mentioned there.

Comment: Also, I TOTALLY disagree that this doesn't relate to development.  This is a web.config..an xml file.  Please, give me a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, did not see the connection string section.  resolved.